# ¿Cómo hacer que una web con recaptcha v3 me verifique como bot?

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, bot, cypress

Tengo un test automatizado con cypress y js que interactúa con un formulario de una web, la cuál ahora ha sido implementada con recaptcha v3. Creía que el recaptcha reconocería el test de cypress y lo puntuaría como bot (score <= 0.5) pero no fue así.

¿Como puedo hacer que el test de cypress sea puntuado **a propósito** como bot luego de completar el input del formulario, hay algún comando o configuración para ello?

Sección de codigo:

```
When('El usuario completa su DNI {string}',(dni)=>{
    homePage.getInputDNI().type(dni)
});
```

Comment: Pro tip: NO TIENES QUE GRITAR. En ninguna parte de la pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para simular que el test de Cypress sea puntuado como un bot por reCAPTCHA v3, puedes utilizar la función window.grecaptcha.execute proporcionada por el propio reCAPTCHA. Esta función te permite ejecutar manualmente la evaluación de reCAPTCHA con un score específico.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo puedes utilizarlo en tu código de Cypress:

```
When('El usuario completa su DNI {string}', (dni) => {
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    // Sobrescribe la función execute de reCAPTCHA
    win.grecaptcha.execute = (siteKey, options) => {
      // Aquí puedes establecer manualmente el score que deseas
      const score = 0.3; // Por ejemplo, establece un score bajo para que sea puntuado como bot

      // Llama a la función onExecute para simular el comportamiento normal
      options.callback(score);
    };

    // Ingresa el valor del DNI en el formulario
    homePage.getInputDNI().type(dni);

    // Continúa con el resto de la prueba...
  });
});
```

Con este código, estás sobrescribiendo la función execute de reCAPTCHA para establecer manualmente el score que deseas. En este ejemplo, se establece un score de 0.3, que debería ser suficiente para que el formulario sea puntuado como bot.

Ten en cuenta que esta solución depende de la implementación actual de reCAPTCHA y podría dejar de funcionar si se realizan cambios en la biblioteca.

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.